# mod_rewrite: How to disable not clean urls navigation of rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been enabled mod_rewrite module and all is right.

I created simple rules for the url, but how do I disable the url navigation (rewritten) with the parameters?

example:

```
# rewrite rule for cleaning
RewriteRule ^bookstore/([0-9]+)?$ /bookstore/book.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Now, if I navigate to http://mydomine.com/bookstore/123 all is done, but the url http://mydomine.com/bookstore/book.php?id=123 is also navigable.

How can I make visible and bavigable only the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the same htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /bookstore/book\.php\?id=([0-9]*)
RewriteRule ^bookstore/book\.php$ /bookstore/%1? [L,R=301]
```

This will 301 redirect requests for the URI with query strings to the one without.

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked properly, except for one thing:

When I navigate the link http://mydomine.com/bookstore/123 the querystring parameter/value will be automatically appended and this is the result:

http://mydomine.com/bookstore/123?id=123

Pls, can you help me again fore remove the appended querystring (id=123)?

Comment: @Gabrik I forgot the `?` at the end of `/bookstore/%1`, edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure about this, but I think that if you rewrite A to B, then both A and B will work.

I would like to ask **why** exactly is it a problem that http://mydomine.com/bookstore/book.php?id=123 is navigable too? What is the problem if that link is valid too, and the user can use both links... although it would take them some time and luck to discover the second option. What would they *gain* by doing that? What would you *lose*? If the answer in both cases is "nothing", then simply stop worrying. :) If you used the old links previously and now replace then with new links, then it is a *good* thing that your customer's old bookmarks will still work.

But assuming that you have a good reason for disabling the old URLs, how about changing them both. For example rename "book.php" to "xyz.php" and then redirect http://mydomine.com/bookstore/123 to http://mydomine.com/bookstore/xyz.php?id=123 -- and the old http://mydomine.com/bookstore/book.php?id=123 will stop working.

Ok, *that* is an *ugly* solution, but you can make it nicer if instead of renaming the files you just move them to a subdirectory, like http://mydomine.com/xyz/bookstore/book.php?id=123 . Alternatively, you could use the redirect to add a "secret" parameter and then check it in the PHP file, for example rewrite http://mydomine.com/bookstore/123 to http://mydomine.com/bookstore/book.php?id=123&secret=xyz . Sure, it's just a "security by obscurity", but again... what exactly would anyone *gain* by discovering your true URLs?

Comment: Your thinks are right. We're in the main release and the customer asked to have only clean urls, this is the reason.

Of course, is good doing to mantain the old urls as you wrote, for let the users/customers be able to acces to old urls links